# Mongodb aggregate, object sum inside object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to agregate data in mongoDb. 
This request perfectly works:

```
db.getCollection('map').aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$Support",
        gross: { $sum :"$Budget.Gross"},
    }}        
])
```

But, I'd prefere to have something like:

```
db.getCollection('map').aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$Support",
        Budget: { gross: { $sum :"$Budget.Gross"}},
    }}        
])
```

Which doesn't work, saying: "The field 'Budget' must me an accumulator object".
I understand why it is not possible to do it in that way. MongoDb doesn't know how to agregate { gross: { $sum :"$Budget.Gross"}}.

But, is there any way to obtain such a result ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**`$projection`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to reshape the the output accordingly

```
db.getCollection('map').aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$Support",
    "gross": { "$sum": "$Budget.Gross" },
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "Budget": { "gross": "$gross" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!